# Download documents from https site Error: sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: python-3.x, openssl, ssl-certificate, pycurl

Anaconda - Python 3.6 
OpenSSL 1.0.2
Operating System: Windows 7

Phase 1 (Completed): Using selenium: launched, navigated, and extracted various data elements including a table from site.  Extracted Hyperlinks contained in table that are direct links to documents.

Phase 2: Taking extracted hyperlink from table I need to download the files to a specified folder on the shared drive.

Tried:

```
import urllib.request
url = 'tts website/test.doc'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,'C:\Users\User\Desktop\')
```

Error I get is sslv3 alert handshake failure

With the site opened, I have clicked on the Lock icon and clicked "Install Certificate".  I have saved the certificate to my "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" in the Certificate store.

I can see the certificate name (when i installed certificate) from the above step in the 58 CA Certificates shown by running the following code:

```
import socket
import ssl
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
context.load_default_certs()
ca_certs = context.get_ca_certs()
print('{} CA Certificates loaded: ' .format(len(ca_certs)))
for cert_dict in ca_certs:
    print(cert_dict['subject'])
print()
```

I can't figure out how to secure a SSL connection to the website/server in order to download the file from each of the hyperlinks??  This website uses Single Sign On(SSO) and automatically logins me in when I first launch the website.

I have tried to use server server.net 443 to connect to server, but can't seem to get the scripting right to connect and retrieve the document.

I have connected directly to the server and abstracted the certificate details shown here:

```
HOST, PORT = server.net, 443
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
s = ctx.wrap_socket(socket.socket(), server_hostname=HOST)
c.connect((HOST, PORT))
cert = s.getpeercert()
print(cert)
```

When i run urlretrieve i am still getting the same error: handshake.  When reviewing my ca certificates i see there is a Personal certificate for my Windows login (username) listed there, that must be how it is automatically logging me in using SSO.  How do i take all of this information, connect to the website using my SSO, and retrieve the documents?

**Latest UPDATE:**
I am finding pycurl to be promising, however I feel like I need a little assistance making a few tweaks to get it working.

```
import pycurl 
fp = open('Test.doc','wb')
curl = pycurl.Curl()
curl.setopt(pycurl.URL, url)  # see url link to go to word doc
curl.setopt(pycurl.FOLLOWLOCATION, 1)
curl.setopt(pycurl.MAXREDIRS, 5)
curl.setopt(pycurl.CONNECTTIMEOUT,30)
curl.setopt(pycurl.TIMEOUT, 300)
try: 
    curl.setopt(pycurl.WRITEDATA, fp)
    curl.perform()
except:
    import traceback
    traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stderr)
    sys.stderr.flush()

curl.close()
fp.close()
```

This code yields no error, however the created word doc contains an error displaying a print screen of the log on page of the website.

**Main Problem:** HTTPS connection using Single Signon connection behind a corporate network proxy server.

I have been trying to get this to work to validate cacert, but I have been getting this error message now:

```
curl.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1)
curl.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYPEER, 2)
curl.setopt(pycurl.CAINFO, certifi.where())
```

but now i am getting ERROR: 51, CERT_TRUST_IS_UNTRUSTED_ROOT

How do i add proxy if that is causing the error? and Secondly, how do i attach the ca certificate file directly?